# Storing single form table questions in 1 or multiple tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design, database-normalization

I have been coding ASP.NET forms inside web applications for a long time now. Generally most web apps have a user that logs in, picks a form to fill out and answers questions so your table looks like this

```
Table: tblInspectionForm
Fields:
inspectionformid (either autoint or guid)
userid (user ID who entered it)
datestamp (added, modified, whatever)
Question1Answer: boolean (maybe a yes/no)
Question2Answer: int (maybe foreign key for sub table 1 with dropdown values)
Question3Answer: int (foreign key for sub table 2 with dropdown values)
```

If I'm not mistaken it meets both 2nd and 3rd normal forms. You're not storing user names in the tables, just the ID's. You aren't storing the dropdown or "yes/no" values in Q-3, just ID's of other tables.

However, *IF* all the questions are exactly the same data type (assume there's no Q1 or Q1 is also an int), which link to the exact same foreign key (e.g. a form that has 20 questions, all on a 1-10 scale or have the same answers to chose from), would it be better to do something like this?

```
so .. Table: tblInspectionForm
userid (user ID who entered it)
datestamp (added, modified, whatever)
... and that's it for table 1 .. then

Table2: tblInspectionAnswers
inspectionformid (composite key that links back to table1 record)
userid (composite key that links back to table1 record)
datastamp  (composite key that links back to table1 record)
QuestionIDNumber: int (question 1, question 2, question3)
QuestionAnswer: int (foreign key)
```

This wouldn't just apply to forms that only have the same types of answers for a single form. Maybe your form has 10 of these 1-10 ratings (int), 10 boolean-valued questions, and then 10 freeform.. You could break it into three tables.

The disadvantage would be that when you save the form, you're making 1 call for every question on your form. The upside is, if you have a lot of nightly integrations or replications that pull your data, if you decide to add a new question, you don't have to manually modify any replications to reporting data sources or anything else that's been designed to read/query your form data. If you originally had 20 questions and you deploy a change to your app that adds a 21st, it will automatically get pulled into any outside replications, data sources, reporting that queries this data. Another advantage is that if you have a REALLY LONG (this happens a lot maybe in the real estate industry when you have inspection forms with 100's of questions that go beyond the 8k limit for a table row) you won't end up running into problems.

Would this kind of scenario ever been the preferred way of saving form data?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, whenever you see a set of columns with numbers in their names, you know the database is poorly designed.
What you want to do in most cases is have a table for the form / questionnaire, a table for the questions, a table for the potential answers (for multiple-choice questions), and a table for answers that the user chooses.
You might also need a table for question type (i.e free-text, multiple-choice, yes/no).
Basically, the schema should look like this:

```
create table Forms
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null, -- with a unique index
    -- other form related fields here
)
create table QuestionTypes
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null, -- with a unique index
)

create table Questions
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    form_id int not null foreign key references Forms(id),
    type_id int not null foreign key references QuestionTypes(id),
    content varchar(1000)
)

create table Answers
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    question_id int not null foreign key references Questions(id),
    content varchar(1000)
    -- For quizez, unremark the next row:
    -- isCorrect bit not null
)

create table Results
{
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    form_id int not null foreign key references Forms(id)
    -- in case only registered users can fill the form, unremark the next row
    --user_id int not null foreign key references Users(id), 
}

create table UserAnswers
(
    result_id int not null foreign key references Results(id), 
    question_id int not null foreign key references Questions(id), 
    answer_id int not null foreign key references Answers(id),
    content varchar(1000) null -- for free text questions
)
```

This design will require a few joins when generating the forms (and if you have multiple forms per application, you just add an application table that the form can reference), and a few joins to get the results, but it's the best dynamic forms database design I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's "preferred" but I have certainly seen that format used commercially.

You could potentially make the secondary table more flexible with multiple answer columns (answer_int, answer_varchar, answer_datetime), and assign a question value that you can relate to get the answer from the right column.

So if q_var = 2 you know to look in answer_varchar, whereas q_value=1 you know is an int and requires a lookup (the name of which could also be specified with the question and stored in a column).

I use an application at the moment which splits answers into combobox, textfield, numeric, date etc in this fashion. The application actually uses a JSON form which splits out the data as it saves into the separate columns. It's a bit flawed as it saves JSON into these columns but the principle can work.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a single identity field for the parent table key that the child table would reference.